# A Question Regarding the Origin of the Axiom of Symmetry

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, translation-request

It is my understanding that Chris Freiling's "Axiom of Symmetry" is based on a counterexample to CH given by Sierpinski in his book "Hypothese de continu".  Since I neither read nor speak French, I was wondering whether anyone who was familiar with his counterexample would be kind enough to provide me with the English translation.  Thanks in advance for your help.  It is greatly appreciated.  Also, is there a translation of Sierpinski's book available?

Comment: As I understand it, the connection with Sierpiński is simply that he proved that the axiom of symmetry is equivalent to the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry) actually has a proof of a more general result.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, that's all well and good, but I would like an English translation of this theorem in his book, just to see if the wording actually matches up with what, say, the Wikipedia article you mention says it says.  Why?  For example, in John C. Simms paper,"Another Characterization of Alephs:  Decompositions of Hyperspace" (Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, Vol 38, Number 1, Winter 1997), he claims the relevant Sierpinski theorem is the following:  "CH if and only if $\exists$S$\subseteq$$\mathbf R^2$ such that: 1. every horizontal cross-section of S is countable and (cont.)

Comment: 2.  every vertical cross-section of S is co-countable, that is, every vertical cross-section of $\mathbf R^2$\S is countable".  Simms further claims Freiling's principles are related to this Sierpinski theorem I quoted from his (Simms') paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the comments, this appears to be his

> **Proposition** $P_1$: $\Bbb R^2$ is the union of two sets, of which one has countable intersection with each line parallel to the $y$-axis, and the other countable intersection with each line parallel to the $x$-axis.

(I’ve modernized the language slightly as well as translating it.) His first result in Chapter $1$ is that this is equivalent to $\mathsf{CH}$.

This is clearly equivalent to the result stated in the Simms paper that you mention in the comments. Its equivalence to the negation of the axiom of symmetry isn’t in Sierpiński, so far as I can tell at a quick look, but the equivalence is very easily established.

Let $S$ be as in that result. For $x\in\Bbb R$ let

$$f(x)=\{y\in\Bbb R:\langle y,x\rangle\in S\text{ or }\langle x,y\rangle\notin S\}\;,$$

a countable subset of $\Bbb R$. For distinct $x,y\in\Bbb R$ we have

$$y\notin f(x)\quad\text{ iff }\quad\langle y,x\rangle\notin S\text{ and }\langle x,y\rangle\in S\tag{1}$$

and

$$x\notin f(y)\quad\text{ iff }\quad\langle x,y\rangle\notin S\text{ and }\langle y,x\rangle\in S\;;\tag{2}$$

clearly $(1)$ and $(2)$ are incompatible, so Freiling’s axiom of symmetry fails.

Now suppose that a function $f$ that assigns to each real number a countable set of reals is a counterexample to Freiling’s axiom of symmetry: there do not exist distinct $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\notin f(y)$ and $y\notin f(x)$. Without loss of generality $x\in f(x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. Let

$$S=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R}\big(\{x\}\times f(x)\big)$$

and

$$T=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R}\big(f(x)\times\{x\}\big)\;.$$

If $\langle x,y\rangle\notin S$, then $y\notin f(x)$, so $x\in f(y)$, and $\langle x,y\rangle\in T$. Similarly, if $\langle x,y\rangle\notin T$, then $x\notin f(y)$, so $y\in f(x)$, and $\langle x,y\rangle\in S$. $S$ and $T$ are now two sets as in Proposition $P_1$, so $\mathsf{CH}$ holds by Sierpiński’s result.